# How can I adjust the volume of my apps sound effects in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, audio

I have some button click sound effects in my app.  They are a bit loud to say the least.  I want to tone it down a bit.  Ive adjusted the volume of the Wav file in Audacity, however when played in the app its back at full volume, Can i adjust the volume in my code at all?

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"btn2", CFSTR 
                                          ("wav"), NULL);
UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [setVolume:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of NSSound class.

> - (void)setVolume:(float)volume
>     The valid range is between 0.0 and 1.0.
>     This method does not affect the systemwide volume.

Comment: Why has this question been accepted? NSSound is not part of the iOS SDK.